# How to resample the result of scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d to another grid size?

Tags: python, arrays, scipy

I use scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d to sample my data from a continuous grid to a discrete grid with a set bin size (i.e. 0.1). Is there a simple way to sample that result to another, coarser grid (i.e. bin size of 1)?

My code using binned_statistic_2d:

```
        statistic, xedges, yedges, binnumber = stats.binned_statistic_2d(
            x, y, values=z, statistic='mean',
            bins=[NX, NY],
            range=[[xmin,xmax], [ymin,ymax]])
```

I could simply change NX/NY here, but I want to drop the original data and perform the resampling later with just the resulting `statistic` variable, which is a 2D array. I could simply loop over the array to recreate 1D arrays require by binned_statistic_2d, but since the dataset can be quite large I think that would be rather inefficient. I think there must be a smarter/faster way to do this.